# google maps api v3 uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Im going through a HTML5 book that includes geolocation, which I've been able to figure out. However, the next step is to include a map using the google maps API. I've already gotten an API key and have structured everything just like the book and the google documentation said, but I can't seem to figure out this problem. On line 29 in the main.js file on http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/projects/Geolocation/, there is an: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot  read property 'offsetWidth' of null. I've searched google and so far nothing has worked. I even defined the height and width of the map in the css file on the site.

Any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you using? Your page works fine in Firefox 3.6.21 (Geolocation is wildly out because I'm in the UK, but there are no errors).

Comment: im using google chrome..on firefox it didn't work for me...in the firefox version it loaded a map?

Comment: Yes, there were no errors reported in the error console and a map was shown.

Comment: I fixed it about an hour ago so now I'm not sure if it works because I fixed it or just because firefox works differently than Chrome, but thanks for the update!

Comment: There isn't a great deal of time elapsed between your question and my initial comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i've been on your page and i saw this :

```
<div id="map>
```

Close the property like that :

```
<div id="map">
```

It could fix some problems :)

Comment: wow that actually worked! Thanks! ....but isn't that invalid html? And shouldn't the initial id declaration work and not be necessary to include both declarataions?

Comment: The <div id="map> was an invalid HTML Tag, you always have to close properties inside tags !
In fact, the problem was when you tried to find the element with "map" as ID, it didn't exists because the ID of the div was "map > ..." for him :)